# Number of solutions of a linear equation in a small subset. 

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be  a prime.  Let  $F_p$ be the finite field of
$p$ elements. Let $A$ be a  subset of $F_p$ of size $s$.
Assume that $s > 2$ is polylogarithmic in  $p$.

Suppose that we want to count number of solutions of
    $$ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = t (\mod\ p) $$ 
under the restriction that $x_i \in A $ for all $1\leq i\leq k$.
The expectation seems to be $s^k/p$ if $k$ is large, independent of $t$.

My question is:  Does there exist $A$  such that the expectation
is known to be quite sharp (namely that the error term is  poly(k p) 
in absolute value)?

Thanks  a lot

Comment: I am a little be confused by your terminology: what does "$s$ polylogarithmic in $p$" mean?

Comment: "$s$ is polylogarithmic in $p$" generally means $s = \Theta(\log^c p)$ for a fixed constant $c > 0$.

Comment: But then I can't follow the claim about the expectation to be independent of $t$: take $A$ to be $\lbrace 0,1,\dots,s-1\rbrace$, so that only $t<ks$ can be expressed in the required form... By the way for this form of $A$ one can easily count the number of solutions.

Comment: In my question k is large. In fact, the case most interesting to me 
is when  k = p. So the expectation of number of solutions is independent of t, I guess. Error term will be dependent on t of course.

Qi 